# Transpose data.frame r

Tags: r

I have my data frame:

```
Name  Time  Event
Serg  15    Log1
Nate  15    Log2
Serg  10    Log3
Nate   9    Log1
Nate  20    Log5
```

And I want to transpose it by time for every `Name` by `time` like this:

```
Name 1     2     3
Serg Log3  Log1  NA
Nate Log1  Log2  Log5
```

Hope I explained clearly! Thanks

Comment: in your desider output, for row named Serg did your pick `Log3` asthe first value by accident or on purpose?

Comment: never mind I see the pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), then `dcast` the dataset to 'wide' format by creating a sequence id (`rowid` - from `data.table` does that for the 'Name' variable), pass it on the formula, and specify the `value.var` as "Event"

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[order(Name, Time)], Name ~ rowid(Name), value.var =  "Event")
#   Name    1    2    3
#1: Nate Log1 Log2 Log5
#2: Serg Log3 Log1   NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    arrange(Name, Time) %>%
    mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
    select(-Time) %>% 
    spread(ind, Event)
#    Name   `1`   `2`   `3`
#* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1  Nate  Log1  Log2  Log5
#2  Serg  Log3  Log1  <NA>
```

Comment: Output isn't correct because in name Serg  Log3 must be in the first column because its time is less than Log1 has.

Comment: @Smasell The output is corrected.  Sorry, didn't check the order before